# Eclipse Model Tool - Two sided transformation ( model to code and code to model )

Tags: eclipse, modeling, papyrus, modelio

is there any tool that i want to generate model from code, and code from model? Especially i prefer this tool should be compatible with eclipse java project .
When i update my code, model must be updated according to changes in code. Also when i update model, code must be updated according to changes in model.

I investigated modelio, papyrus , i am not sure whether or not they support this feature.

Thank you.

Comment: Stackoverflow does not deal with tool recommendation. I am pretty sure that these tools have support, forum, documentation ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modelio** support it with the **module Java Designer**.
May be these demos "[Edit Java code in Modelio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzcxzxKiFAk)" and "[Overview of JavaDesigner module](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_3hZ91ulmI)" can help you. These demos have been done with Modelio 2 and, currently, Modelio is in version 3.3 so you can encounter some differences in the interface but globally it works in the same way.
For more information about this open source module, you can consult its [wiki](http://forge.modelio.org/projects/javadesigner-modelio3-user-manual-english/wiki).

Hope this helps.